# Training DL model on slurm and it's getting slow

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, slurm

my school started to let their student use GPU server. So I'm training DL model through slurm.

```
salloc -p p3 -J chem_proj --mincpus=16 --mem=64G --time=2-00:00:00 --gres=gpu:a40:1 srun --pty bash
```

I got resources by using above line. (got 16 cpus, 64GB, one A40 gpu for 2 days).
And I launched my jupyter sessions with this line

```
singularity exec --nv /shared/public/images/docker_image.sif jupyter lab --no-browser --ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xx --port=xxxx
```

On first epoch, It takes only 45 minutes to train. But from next epoch it's dramatically getting slow.

tqdm module indicates it might takes 5 hours for next epoch.

And I often have disconnection error while I'm training next epoch(I mean epoch 2)

I changed batch size 512 -> 256 but it's same.

GPU memory usage is 15GB/40GB (roughly)

Please let me know what I need to check.

Comment: Singularity is old and NVIDIA's first love is Docker. I mean they have entire NGC website full of Docker images. The problem might be the Singularity version or how optimised the container is for ML training. A better way is the pull highly optimised NGC containers for tf or pytorch. Here is a link: https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/how-to-run-ngc-deep-learning-containers-with-singularity/

Comment: @PrakharSharma Thanks for information. But I've already pull NGC image and I just added few modules for my project.

Comment: it is very hard to tell the exact problem. try without `ipynb` files. make a new `.py` files and submit jobs using `sbatch`. interactive job may be an overkill.

Comment: @PrakharSharma Yes, I'm also considering that! Thx!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a memory (RAM) issue. Have you checked the RAM usage during the second epoch? Could you try reducing the memory allocation (`--mem=32G`)?

Something similar happened to me when I was training a pytorch-based model with a data generator which didn't explicitly delete training data from previous epochs. I had to explicitly delete the corresponding tensors and call `gc.collect()` to make sure they didn't stay allocated in the memory.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience, I'll try this and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue with moving my training data into local drive.

My remote server(school server) policy was storing personel data into NAS. And file i/o from NAS proveked heavy load on network. It was also affected by other user's file i/o from NAS.

After I moved training data into NAS, everything is fine.

(As far as I know, Slurm system recommend user save their data to NAS.)